# Easier or better way to draw 1d array

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm trying to reproduce the following figure, and was wondering if there was a simpler way.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\leftbracket{[}
\def\rightbracket{]}

\tikzset{my arrow/.style={
  blue!60!black,
  -latex
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,column sep=5.6mm, nodes in empty cells
] (P)
{
& t0 & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=,row sep=0mm,
column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}
] (O)
{
v1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
};


\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,column sep=5.6mm, nodes in empty cells
] (P)
{
& + & + & + & + & + & +\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=,row sep=8mm,
column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}
] (O)
{
v2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
v1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10\\
};

\draw[my arrow] (O-1-2) to (O-2-2);
\draw[my arrow] (O-1-3) to (O-2-3);
\draw[my arrow] (O-1-4) to (O-2-4);
\draw[my arrow] (O-1-5) to (O-2-5);
\draw[my arrow] (O-1-6) to (O-2-6);
\draw[my arrow] (O-1-7) to (O-2-7);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the time to figure out at all at the moment, but at a first glance I would recommend you to take a look at the foreach loop in tikz. I think it could save you a lot of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,5} {
   \node at (\x, 0) {t\x};
   \node at (\x, -1.5) {+};
   \foreach \y\lbl in {1/1,2/2,3/1} {
    \node [left] at (-1,-\y) {v\lbl};
    \ifnum\y=3
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{2*\x}
     \node (n\x\y) [draw, minimum width=1cm] at (\x, -\y) {\result};
     \draw [->] (n\x2) -- (n\x\y);
    \else
     \node (n\x\y) [draw, minimum width=1cm] at (\x, -\y) {\x};
    \fi
   }
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Rendered image:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way with stacks, instead of `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\mbx#1{\fbox{\makebox[1.5cm]{#1}}}
\def\xdownarrow{\raisebox{-1.9ex}{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{$\downarrow$}{\rule{.5pt}{4ex}\kern.1pt}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\def\boxcol#1#2{\Longstack{%
  t#1\\\mbx{#1}\\$+$\\\mbx{#1}\\\xdownarrow\\\mbx{#2}}\kern-\fboxrule}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{2em}
\begin{document}
\Longstack{\\v1\\\\v2\\\\v1}
\boxcol{0}{0}%
\boxcol{1}{2}%
\boxcol{2}{4}%
\boxcol{3}{6}%
\boxcol{4}{8}%
\boxcol{5}{10}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick to your matrix solution, you can cook up a general setter for columns and rows. The order of execution for each cell style key is given in the manual hence you can set the column properties and then undo unwanted properties in the row settings (at least in this case).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{my arrow/.style={blue!60!black,-latex},
  set@com@col/.style={},set@com@col@aryarg/.style={column #1/.style={set@com@col}},
  set@com@row/.style={},set@com@row@aryarg/.style={row #1/.style={set@com@row}},
  set common column/.style 2 args={set@com@col/.style={#2}, set@com@col@aryarg/.list={#1}},
  set common row/.style 2 args={set@com@row/.style={#2}, set@com@row@aryarg/.list={#1}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=0mm,
set common column={2,...,7}{nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},
set common row={1,3}{nodes={draw=none}},
] (O)
{
& t0 & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5 \\
v1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
& + & + & + & + & + & +\\
v2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\[8mm]
v1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10\\
};

\foreach\x in{2,...,7}{\draw[my arrow] (O-4-\x) to (O-5-\x);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `common row` and `common col` settings. I'll use them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not much different from the other answers really...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \v [count=\y] in {1,2,1}{
  \node [left] at (0,-\y) {$v_\v$};
  \foreach \i [count=\x, evaluate={\j=int(\i+\i);}] in {0,...,5}{
     \node [minimum width=1cm,draw] (cell-\y-\x) at (\x,-\y) {\ifcase\y\or\i\or\i\or\j\fi};
     \ifcase\y
     \or
       \node [above=.25cm] at (\x,-\y) {$t_\i$};
     \or
       \node [above=.25cm] at (\x,-\y) {$+$};
     \else
       \draw [-stealth] (cell-2-\x) -- (cell-3-\x);
     \fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could either use a `\foreach` loop to place the individual columns of your picture:

[image: With loop]

However, this will break if the height of the individual boxes can vary. In that case, you could use a `\matrix[matrix of nodes]` and type in the content manually:

[image: With matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw, minimum width=1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \node at (\i,0) (t\i) {t\i};
    \node[mybox, below=0.3cm of t\i.center] (top\i) {\i};
    \node[mybox, below=1cm of top\i.center] (mid\i) {\i};
    \node[mybox, below=1cm of mid\i.center] (bot\i) {\pgfmathparse{int(2*\i)}\pgfmathresult}
        edge[<-] (mid\i);
    \node at ($(top\i)!0.5!(mid\i)$) (plus\i) {+};
}
\path (top0)[late options={label=left:v1}]
    (mid0)[late options={label=left:v2}]
    (bot0)[late options={label=left:v1}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (matrix) [
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep={0.8cm,between origins}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 2/.style={every node/.append style={mybox}},
    row 4/.style={every node/.append style={mybox}},
    row 5/.style={every node/.append style={mybox}},
]{
                    & t0 & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5\\
    |[draw=none]|v1 & 0  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5 \\
                    & +  & +  & +  & +  & +  & + \\
    |[draw=none]|v2 & 0  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5 \\[0.8cm]
    |[draw=none]|v1 & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10\\
};
\foreach \i in {2,...,7} {
    \draw[->] (matrix-4-\i) -- (matrix-5-\i); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```