# How to draw an 1-D array

Tags: arrays, stack, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to draw something like this: [Easier or better way to draw 1d array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202898/easier-or-better-way-to-draw-1d-array). The problem is that I need to change the value of the second array and I don't know how to do that using stack instead of tikz.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add another argument to the new macro (`\boxcol`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\mbx#1{\fbox{\makebox[1.5cm]{#1}}}
\def\xdownarrow{\raisebox{-1.9ex}{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{$\downarrow$}{\rule{.5pt}{4ex}\kern.1pt}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\newcommand{\boxcol}[3]% #1=first row, #2=second row, #3=third row
{\Longstack{%
  t#1\\\mbx{#1}\\$+$\\\mbx{#2}\\\xdownarrow\\\mbx{#3}}\kern-\fboxrule}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{2em}
\begin{document}
\Longstack{\\v1\\\\v2\\\\v1}
\boxcol{0}{5}{0}%
\boxcol{1}{4}{2}%
\boxcol{2}{3}{4}%
\boxcol{3}{2}{6}%
\boxcol{4}{1}{8}%
\boxcol{5}{0}{10}%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]